# Child Mapping Table is unable to duplicate values in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to implement inheritance but in a way in which is convenient for me to retrieve data. So I have 2 POJOs, one being a parent entity and the other which extends the Parent is the child, Essentially, I'm using the child as a mapper to retrieve values from the Parent table in a key:value pair fashion. So the both keys can be duplicated. Is there any way in which this can be executed. I wanted to create a structure in which one child_Id, can have many different parent_Id's linked to it, in a child_Id:parent_Id, eg. 1:1, 1:2, 2:1, 2:3, 3:1, etc. But due to inheritance I can't duplicate the parent_Id column. Is there a work around. I know it may violate the rules of normalization but is it possible? And if so how?

**Computer.java (Parent Entity)**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name="Computer", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"tac_Code" , "config_Code"})})
@Embeddable
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public abstract class Computer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="laptop_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    protected Long computerId;

    ......

}
```

This is the Child class **ReplacementComputer.java (Child Entity)**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

/**
 * The Class ReplacementComputer
 */
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="computer_id")
public class ReplacementComputer extends Computer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Product.class)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REPLACEMENTComputer_ID")
    protected Collection<Computer> computers = new ArrayList<Computer>();

// ... getters and setters
}
```

After it creates 3 tables a Mapping table for the List in ReplacementComputer_computers, Computer being the parent, and ReplacementComputer. So every computer will have several replacementComputers associated with it, the replacementComputer will map back to the Computer table to retrieve the details. This is the flow in which I'm trying to accomplish. But in MySQLWorkbench, if these combinations exist already,

1 , 2
1 , 3
1 , 4
2 , 1

This is the error I get when  try to persist (2, 3).

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `testingdb1`.`replacement_computer_computers` (`replacement_computer_computer_id`, `computers_computer_id`) VALUES ('2', '3');

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'UK_lbghmganelv3o7oupon6f798c'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `testingdb1`.`replacement_computer_computers` (`replacement_computer_computer_id`, `computers_computer_id`) VALUES ('2', '3')

Any help is well apreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your mappings or how they relate to what you want.  The replacement computer entity is a computer, so every entry/row in the replacement computer table has 1 and only 1 row in the computer table already.  You then setup up ReplacementComputer.computers so that each ReplacementComputer has many computers associated to it, with a join column so that a computer can have 1 and only 1 replacement computer via the REPLACEMENTComputer_ID foriegn key.  Where/how does replacement_computer_computers factor into things?  It looks like the name that would be used to default a M:M table

Comment: And if so, then your annotations are not being used.  Which makes sense, since they shouldn't work - you cannot add a joincolumn definition to a basic mapping, or GeneratedValue to a OneToMany

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to hibernate, I have only used hibernate for simple use case in the past. But you're right I have a one to one relationship in my Computer class which references replacementComputer via a replacementComputer_ID FK, Then I have in the replacement Computer it has a one to many relationship to many computers. I always believed that the joinColumn was used to associate a column from another table, but I see it depends on the way it being used. I figured out that my annotations creates a unique index constraint on the replacement_computer table. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Start by mapping out what you want your database and the relations to look like, as you seem to know that better.  Or start with the object model and model the database around it.  What exactly do you need?  Java inheritance is using the computer_id fk in ReplacementComputer, since a ReplacementComputer must have one and only one row in both the Computer and ReplacementComputer tables - a row in the Computer table cannot represent both a Computer and a separate ReplacementComputer at the same time.  The ReplacementComputer is a separate Computer instance from any other Computer.